# use the return value from a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am tryin to check if I am able to connect to a port using socket.

```
main()

def main():
    if socket():
       print('connected')
def socket():
    try:
        start_socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        ip_port = ('1.2.3.4', 8443)
        res=start_socket.socket.connect_ex(ip_port)
        if res == 0:
            return 1
    except:
         return 0
```

Expected result:

I want that if the code is able to connect to port then it should print connected . But in this case, even if it is not connected it is printing connected

Comment: What are all the possible values of `res`?

Comment: This code looks right except that main() is referenced before it is defined.

Comment: Why do you just have a try-except with no error for the except part?